# What did I miss while converting from CUDA to OpenCL? Or why is my kernel returning different output than serial code

Tags: cuda, opencl

This is my code for multiplication of a sparse matrix in compressed column format

```
__kernel void mykernel(__global int* colvector,
                       __global int* val,
                       __global int* result,
                       __global int* index,
                       __global int* rowptr,
                       __global int* sync )
{   
    __local int vals[1000];
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        result[i]=0;
    }
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

    const int items_per_row=32;//total threads working in a row

    const int thread_id=get_global_id(0)+get_local_id(0);//total threads in the program

    const int warpid = thread_id/items_per_row;//warp id is actual row

    int lane=thread_id&(items_per_row-1);//thread id within the warp

    int row = warpid;

    if(row<4)
    {
        int sum = 0;

        int row_start = rowptr[row];
        int row_end = rowptr[row+1];

        vals[get_global_id(0)]=0;
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
        barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);


        for (int i = row_start+lane; i<row_end; i+=items_per_row)
        {
            vals[get_local_id(0)]+=val[i]*colvector[index[i]];
        }

        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
        barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

        if (lane < 16 ) vals[get_local_id(0)] += vals[get_local_id(0) + 16];

        if (lane < 8 ) vals[get_local_id(0)] += vals[get_local_id(0) + 8];

        if (lane < 4 ) vals[get_local_id(0)] += vals[get_local_id(0) +4];

        if (lane < 2 ) vals[get_local_id(0)] += vals[get_local_id(0) + 2];

        if (lane < 1 ) vals[get_local_id(0)] += vals[get_local_id(0) + 1];

        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
        barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

        if(lane==0)
        {
            result[row] += vals[get_local_id(0)];
        }
    }
}
```

the above OpenCL code was converted from the CUDA code given below:

```
spmv_csr_vector_kernel(const int num_rows,
                       const int * ptr,
                       const int * indices,
                       const float * data,
                       const float * x,
                       float * y )
{
    __shared__ float vals[];

    int thread_id = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x; // global thread index

    int warp_id = thread_id / 32; // global warp index

    int lane = thread_id & (32 - 1); // thread index within the warp

    // one warp per row

    int row = warp_id;

    if (row < num_rows)
    {
        int row_start = ptr[row];

        int row_end = ptr[row+1];

        // compute running sum per thread

        vals[threadIdx.x] = 0;

        for(int jj = row_start + lane; jj < row_end; jj += 32)
        {
            vals[threadIdx.x] += data[jj] * x[indices[jj]];
        }
        // parallel reduction in shared memory

        if (lane < 16) vals[threadIdx.x] += vals[threadIdx.x + 16];

        if (lane < 8) vals[threadIdx.x] += vals[threadIdx.x + 8];

        if (lane < 4) vals[threadIdx.x] += vals[threadIdx.x + 4];

        if (lane < 2) vals[threadIdx.x] += vals[threadIdx.x + 2];

        if (lane < 1) vals[threadIdx.x] += vals[threadIdx.x + 1];

        // first thread writes the result

        if (lane == 0)
        {
            y[row] += vals[threadIdx.x];
        }
    }
}
```

The CUDA code is correct but my OpenCL kernel is not returning correct output. I have been trying for a week now but no solution. Does anybody know what mistake I am making?

Comment: Could you please apply some proper indentation and formatting to your code? It is very hard to read like this.

Comment: @user1660282: not really. it is still a mess

Answer (score 2):

I can at least see one mistake. thread_id is not the same in each code. blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x in CUDA == get_global_id(0) in OpenCL, not get_global_id(0)+get_local_id(0). Also get_local_id(0) == threadIdx.x

Answer (score 0):

Try using swan, this might help you understand your problem.

you can find an article [here](http://gpgpu.org/2010/03/09/swan) about it.